# C++ SQL wrapper/Connection

Tags: c++, sql, template, c++14

Working on my [SQL project](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL) at last.

The concept is easy to use and integrate SQL into C++.

> ```
>     ThorsSQL::Connection    mysql("mysql://host", "username", "password", "databaseName");
>     ThorsSQL::Statement     bigEarnerStat(mysql, 
>                                           "SELECT ID, Name, Salary FROM Employee WHERE Salary > % and Age < %"
>                                           ThorsAnvil::SQL::Prepare);
>
>     // Bind variables to '%' in statement
>     // Then execute the SQL statement.
>     // Call function for every row returned.
>     bigEarnerStat.execute(Bind(1000000, 32), // parameter bound to % in statement.
>         // Function executed for each row returned.
>         // Parameters are matched against the SELECT in the statement.
>         // A bad type conversion will throw an exception.
>         [](u64 id, std::string const& name, int salary){
>             std::cout << name << " is a fat cat earning $" << salary/100 << "." << salary%100 << "\n";
>         }
>     );
> ```

**Connection**:
Represents a single connection to the DB.

The thing to note above is `mysql://host`. The concept being that these classes provide the framework that allows specific DB code to be plugged into (A MySQL variant will be coming to code review soon). So the **"Schema"** part of the URL string specifies the type of DB (and thus what specific plugin the code below uses (see `ConnectionCreatorRegister`)

So the `Connection` object will defer all the DB specific work to the `proxy` member. This class handles all the generic code.

**ConnectionProxy**:
This DB specific code for a connection.

**ConnectionCreatorRegister**:
This allows a DB specific implementation to register itself as a viable alternative.

Note: If you want to try compiling the code I suggest you check it out of the git repo and compile using the instructions there. But Saying that you can potentially compile it using only the source here just add a `main()`.

#### Connection.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_SQL_CONNECTION_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_SQL_CONNECTION_H

#include "SQLUtil.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace SQL
    {
        class Statement;
        class StatementProxy;
        class ConnectionProxy
        {
            public:
                virtual ~ConnectionProxy()  = 0;
                virtual std::unique_ptr<StatementProxy> createStatementProxy(std::string const& statement, StatementType type) = 0;
        };

        inline ConnectionProxy::~ConnectionProxy() {}
        using ConnectionCreator= std::function<std::unique_ptr<ConnectionProxy>(std::string const& host, int port,
                                                                        std::string const& username,
                                                                        std::string const& password,
                                                                        std::string const& database,
                                                                        Options const& options)>;
        class Connection
        {
            private:
                static std::map<std::string, ConnectionCreator>&    getCreators();

                friend class Statement;
                std::unique_ptr<StatementProxy> createStatementProxy(std::string const& statement, StatementType type);

                std::unique_ptr<ConnectionProxy>  proxy;
            public:
                Connection(std::string const& connection,
                            std::string const& username,
                            std::string const& password,
                            std::string const& database,
                            Options const& options = Options{});

                static void registerConnectionType(std::string const& schema, ConnectionCreator creator);
        };

        template<typename T>
        class ConnectionCreatorRegister
        {
            public:
                ConnectionCreatorRegister(std::string const& schema)
                {
                    Connection::registerConnectionType(schema, [](std::string const& host, int port,
                                                                std::string const& username,
                                                                std::string const& password,
                                                                std::string const& database,
                                                                Options const& options)
                    {
                        return std::unique_ptr<ConnectionProxy>(new T(host, port , username, password, database, options));
                    });
                }
        };
    }
} 
#endif
```

#### Connection.cpp

```
#include "Connection.h"
#include "Statement.h"
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::SQL;

Connection::Connection(std::string const& connection,
                       std::string const& username,
                       std::string const& password,
                       std::string const& database,
                       Options const& options)
{
    std::size_t     schemaEnd   = connection.find(':');
    if (schemaEnd == std::string::npos || connection[schemaEnd + 1] != '/' || connection[schemaEnd + 2] != '/') {
        throw std::runtime_error("Connection::Connection: Failed to find schema: " + connection);
    }

    bool        hasPort     = true;
    std::size_t hostEnd     = connection.find(':', schemaEnd + 3);

    if (hostEnd == std::string::npos) {
        hasPort = false;
        hostEnd = connection.size();
    }

    std::string schema      = connection.substr(0, schemaEnd);
    std::string host        = connection.substr(schemaEnd + 3, hostEnd - schemaEnd - 3);
    std::string port        = hasPort ? connection.substr(hostEnd + 1) : "0";

    errno                   = 0;
    char*       endPtr;
    int         portNumber  = std::strtol(port.c_str(), &endPtr, 10);
    auto        creator     = getCreators().find(schema);

    if (host == "" || errno != 0 || *endPtr != '\0') {
        throw std::runtime_error("Connection::Connection: Failed to parse connection: " + connection);
    }

    if (creator == getCreators().end()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Connection::Conection: Schema for unregister DB type: " + schema + " From: " + connection);
    }
    proxy   = creator->second(host, portNumber, username, password, database, options);
}

std::map<std::string, ConnectionCreator>& Connection::getCreators()
{
    static std::map<std::string, ConnectionCreator> creators;
    return creators;
}
void Connection::registerConnectionType(std::string const& schema, ConnectionCreator creator)
{
    getCreators().emplace(schema, creator);
}


std::unique_ptr<StatementProxy> Connection::createStatementProxy(std::string const& statement, StatementType type)
{
    return proxy->createStatementProxy(statement, type);
}
```

#### test/ConnectionTest.cpp

```
#include "Connection.h"
#include "Statement.h"

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "test/MockMysql.h"


ThorsAnvil::SQL::ConnectionCreatorRegister<MockMySQLConnection>   registerFakeMysql("mysql");

TEST(ConnectionTest, Create)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    Connection     connection("mysql://127.0.0.1:69", "root", "testPassword", "test");
}
TEST(ConnectionTest, CreateDefaultPort)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    Connection     connection("mysql://127.0.0.1", "root", "testPassword", "test");
}

TEST(ConnectionTest, BadSchema)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    ASSERT_THROW(
    Connection     connection("badschema://127.0.0.1:69", "root", "testPassword", "test"),
    std::runtime_error
    );
}

TEST(ConnectionTest, NoSchema)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    ASSERT_THROW(
    Connection     connection("127.0.0.1:69", "root", "testPassword", "test"),
    std::runtime_error
    );
}
TEST(ConnectionTest, BadHost)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    ASSERT_THROW(
    Connection     connection("mysql://:69", "root", "testPassword", "test"),
    std::runtime_error
    );
}
TEST(ConnectionTest, BadPort)
{
    using ThorsAnvil::SQL::Connection;
    ASSERT_THROW(
    Connection     connection("mysql://127.0.0.1:XY", "root", "testPassword", "test"),
    std::runtime_error
    );
}
```

Comment: No enough to make an answer, but you might want to use `std::make_unique<T>(...)` rather than `std::unique_ptr<ConnectionProxy>(new T(...))`. A bit cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GCC now has SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631065/why-does-libcs-implementation-of-stdstring-take-up-3x-memory-as-libstdc), with the ABI breaking backwards compatibility and all that. Which probably means you can pass them by value.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't too much to say here, since this code isn't the interest part of the project. Way to set me up with the `bigEarnerStat.execute()` call and then not have a code review for that part. I feel empty inside.

Anyway, mostly minor comments.

Is there a reason for `ConnectionProxy::~ConnectionProxy()` to be pure virtual instead of simply defaulted?

I'm wary of the `ConnectionCreatorRegister` class. It's just there to be able to stick a global variable somewhere to call the `registerConnectionType()` function, but the initialization rules are based on *odr-use* of the variable. You never *odr-use* `registerFakeMysql`, so I'm not sure that you have the guarantee that it will have actually been registered. Startup issues like that are weird.

---

Code-wise, this:

```
return std::unique_ptr<ConnectionProxy>(new T(host, port , username, password, database, options));
```

should be spelled:

```
return std::make_unique<T>(host, port, username, password, database, options);
```

There's no advantage here compared to `make_shared`, but it's shorter and more explicit. We're making a `T`, and this puts that front and center. You could, if you want, throw in a `static_assert` that `std::is_convertible<T*, ConnectionProxy*>` so that the error message will be clearer to your users.

The `Connection()` constructor could be cleaned up. Basically, you start by parsing `connection` into a `schema`, a `host`, and a `port`. We could factor that out into a separate type and a function:

```
struct ConnectionParts { // or better name
    std::string schema;
    std::string host;
    int port;

    static ConnectionParts parse(std::string const& );
};

Connection(std::string const& connection,
           std::string const& username,
           std::string const& password,
           std::string const& database,
           Options const& options)
: Connection(ConnectionParts::parse(connection), username, password, database, options)
{ }

Connection(ConnectionParts const& parts, ...)
{ ... }
```

That'll also let the user pass in the `schema`, `host`, and `port` independently themselves if that's what they want to do. Just makes it more usable, and you don't lose anything.

Lastly, I'm not a fan of lining up the `=`s. It takes a lot of work on the coding side to actually do that, and I find it makes the code *much* harder to read. You have to scan a lot further to find the important bits. Especially when you're indenting the variable names too, like:

```
auto        creator     = getCreators().find(schema);
    <------>       <--->
```

Too much screen real estate. Just do:

```
auto creator = getCreators().find(schema);
```